# Javafx fadetransition opacity bug

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

I am using Fade transitions as Parallel Transition's child in my project. I changed button's opacity for my business logic 1 to 0. When I changed a irrelevant ToggleButtons' (which is not child of fade or parallel transition)style by using setStyle() method, irrelevant ToggleButton's opacity changes, I think its with the transition's time frame but I can't work it out.

Buttons are painted red with this code.

```
    try {
        if (thePane.getChildren() != null) {
            for (Node node : thePane.getChildren()) {
                if (node instanceof GridPane) {
                    ObservableList<Node> nodes = ((GridPane) node).getChildren();
                    for (Node node1 : nodes) {
                        if (node1 instanceof ToggleButton) {
                            ToggleButton toggle= ((ToggleButton) node1);
                            if (toggle!= null) {
                                if (toggle.getId().equals(id)) {
                                    if (toggle.isSelected()) {
                                        toggle.styleProperty().setValue("-fx-background-color: #ff0000,linear-gradient(#a81010 0%, #ba2525 20%, #ea2525 100%),linear-gradient(#a81010, #ea2525),radial-gradient(center 50% 0%, radius 100%, rgba(214,21,21,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,0));");
                                    } else {
                                        toggle.styleProperty().setValue("-fx-background-color:  #a50000,linear-gradient(#870909 0%, #c93434 20%, #a00303 100%), linear-gradient(#870909, #a00303), radial-gradient(center 50% 0%, radius 100%, rgba(148,114,114,0.9), rgba(255,255,255,0));");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And adding some buttons to FadeTransition as child of Paralleltransition to make flash, with this lines.

```
    try{
        ToggleButton toggle= getToggleButton();

        FadeTransition fadeTransition = new FadeTransition(Duration.seconds(0.9), toggle);

        fadeTransition.setNode(toggle);
        fadeTransition.setFromValue(10.0);
        fadeTransition.setToValue(0.0);
        fadeTransition.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

        if (fadeTransitionList.get(toggle.getId()) == null) {
            parallelTransition.stop();
            parallelTransition.getChildren().add(fadeTransition);
            parallelTransition.play();
            fadeTransitionList.put(toggle.getId(), fadeTransition);
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

As i said, irrelevant buttons (which has not been added to ParallelTransition (also FadeTransition)'s) opacity changes.

I think Fade Transition in JavaFX runs for a region in the screen, and the region affects unrelated buttons

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are asking for help in debugging your program, i.e. finding out why it doesn't behave as expected. In order for me to do that, I need to run your code on my machine and try to reproduce the problem. This is stated in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) under the heading **Help others reproduce the problem**. Hence, in order for me to help you, I ask you to [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. Of-course, I am speaking only for myself.

Comment: I am working on a secret project unfortunately, I do my best to describe the problem, I think Fade Transition runs for a region in the screen, and the screen affects unrelated buttons.

Comment: You don't have to show us your real code. Simply creating a [mre] demonstrating the problem is enough.

Comment: Two tips about your code: I'm not familiar with JavaFx but I'm sure that there is a better way of recovering a ToggleButton by id than the one you have pasted in your first excerpt. Maybe the method "lookup"? And notice that if you use instanceof, you don't need to test nullable after. First thing is making your code more readable reducing useless sentences. Have you installed "sonalint" in your IDE?

Comment: Thanks Rubio, The project is legacy, and not tested well, I am changing code as much little as possible, and I love your info about instance of.